# "being" vs "were" after "due to"

Tags: passive-voice

Which of the following sentence is grammatically correct?

> Revenue declined due to lesser units of property **being** sold in 2013.

or

> Revenue declined due to lesser units of property **were** sold in 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Revenue declined due to lesser units of property being sold in 2013.

Is grammatically correct. "being sold in 2013" is a participle phrase that acts as an adjective to "units of property".

You can use the participle (being) as and adjective, but not the conjugated<sup>[1]</sup> verb form (were).

A point about "lesser": this seems to indicate that the units of property that were being sold (adding "that" would make the second sentence correct!) are of lower quality compared to others. If you simply refer to the number of units that were sold, I would use **less**.

A bit more details about why this sentence is wrong:

> *Revenue declined due to lesser units of property were sold in 2013.

From [here](http://www.learnamericanenglishonline.com/Violet%20Level/V5%20Due%20to.html) (Emphasis mine):

> "Due to" is very similar to "because of." It gives a reason for why something is true. You can use "due to" with phrases and single words, **but you can't use "due to" with a clause**.

Now "units of property were sold in 2013" is a clause, and should not be used after due to.

You could however substitute **because** for *due to*, and the sentence would be fine, as J.R. pointed out. This is because *because* can join two clauses.

<sup>[1]</sup> Conjugated, not declined, of course. Thank you @SnailPlane, and my apologies for confusing anyone, including @Pupu!

Comment: Thanks.  "being sold in 2013" is it a participle phrase ?

Comment: Yes it is, I added it to my answer :)

Comment: By the way, what is declined verb ?

Comment: A verb that has been changed from its _infinitive_ form to match person, number, tense, modality, etc. If the infinitive is "be", declined form are (I) _am_, (you) _were_, etc.

Comment: aaarrgh. _hangs head in shame_. once again messed up my terminology :'(

Comment: Oerkelens, JR, SnailPlane, Lucian, Thanks for all your helps. But I really can't see why the second sentence is incorrect

Comment: @Pupu: Because the verb form "were" would need a subject. There is no subject in that sentence.

Comment: I thought "property were sold "is in passive woice

Comment: Yes, but it is a clause. After _due to_ you can have a noun, a phrase, but not a clause. See my edit :)

Answer (score 2):

It's the first one ("being sold"), although, interestingly enough, that isn't the case when you change *due to* to *because*:

> Revenue declined due to lesser units being sold in 2013.
>
> Revenue declined because lesser units were sold in 2013.

Comment: Oerkelens, JR, SnailPlane, Lucian, Thanks for all your helps.  But I really can't see why the second sentence is incorrect.

Comment: In sentences like these, _due to_ doesn't take the same words that come after _because_. That's why we can say: _The picnic was cancelled because it was raining_, but we'd say: _The picnic was cancelled due to rain_. Too bad your question focused on this particular example with units of property. Had you asked a more generic question, you might have gotten a more elaborate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that anyway with these small changes:

> Revenue declined due to lesser units of property **which** were being sold in 2013.
>
> Revenue declined due to lesser units of property **which** were sold in 2013.

Answer (score 0):

After a preposition or a preposition group such as "due to sth" you can only use a noun or the noun-form of a verb (the gerund). 
Of course, you can replace a noun by a pronoun, but that's basic grammar knowledge.